# R package patchwork : titles for rows/columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, patchwork

Is there a way to add titles by row or column using the patchwork package for combining plots? 
Ex. with the arrangement : patchwork<- (p| p2 | p3)/ (p4| p5| p6), I would like one title for plots 1-3 and another for 4-6.

Comment: I think this could be achievable by using [tagging](https://patchwork.data-imaginist.com/articles/guides/annotation.html)

Comment: I could think of three workarounds: **(1)** setting the plot titles/axis labels in ggplot  directly (and omit some) can create the impression of overarching axis labels, **(2)** Using ggplot's [facet_wrap](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html) can be an option as that has overarching row/column titles (but only if your data structure works with facet_wrap). **(3)** A ["grob"](https://community.rstudio.com/t/common-axis-title-in-grid-arrange/96353) instead of patchwork might help. But often found myself needing to use Powerpoint/Illustrator.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is a way to put labels for rows or columns in arrangements of plots generated with `patchwork` by using a `textGrob` as suggested by in one of the comments:

```
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species,y=Petal.Length)) + geom_boxplot()
p2 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species,y=Sepal.Length)) + geom_boxplot()

row_label_1 <- wrap_elements(panel = textGrob('First Row', rot=90))
row_label_2 <- wrap_elements(panel = textGrob('First Row', rot=90))

p_all <- (row_label_1 | p1 | p2) / (row_label_2 | p1| p2) +
          plot_layout(widths = c(.1,1,1))  # adjust with
```

[image: Patchwork assembly with row labels]

Comment: Thanks, this still seems to be the only way to do it. Should be mentioned that `textGrob()` is in the `grid`-package. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/322) for row/column titles on github. Please give it a thumbs up if you also would like to have this feature in patchwork!